# Tooltip/hover-text in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display a tooltip or hover-text in a list-menu whereby if the user select that value, there will be additional text provided. Is it possible ? As the data is currently stored in a hard-coded array.

```
Code:
<select name="Interests" id="Interests">
 <?php $arr = array('', 'cycling', 'badminton', 'jetskiing', 'ice-skating');
 for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
 {
    echo "<option value=\"{$arr[$i]}\" {$selected}>{$arr[$i]}</option>\n"; 
 }
?>
</select>
```

So if I select the cycling, there should be text appearing on the list-menu. Kindly advise. Thanks!

Comment: you'd have to do this through javascript since `option` elements don't support the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. It uses jQuery, since you can't use the `title`-attribute and you can't put another child element into the `select`-Container, it wouldn't be valid HTML.

#### See the Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/DLyMG/

#### How it works

The trick with this is, to bind the hover `interests.hover`. The first function is triggered when you're over the `select`-box, the second is triggered when you leave. I added a `timeout` for this reason: When the user selects something, he moves out of the element (because the list is longer than the element itself). So, when he selects something, he would also trigger the `mouseout` event, therefore we have the `timeout`.

The second thing is to bind the `onchange`-event, which is done below. When the user selects a value, the content of the tooltip is changed and you can add any text or HTML as you like.

#### Javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var interests       = $('#Interests');
    var tooltip         = $('#tooltip');
    var tooltipInfo     = $('#tooltip_info');

    interests.hover(
        function() {
            tooltip.fadeIn(200);
        },
        function() {
            setTimeout ( function () {
                tooltip.fadeOut(200); tooltipInfo.html();
            }, 1000);
        }
    );

    interests.bind('change', function() {
        tooltipInfo.html('user has changed the value');
    });

});

</script>
```

#### CSS

```
<style>

aside.tooltip {
    display:        none;
    position:       absolute;
    top:            20px;
    left:           300px;
}

</style>
```

#### HTML

```
<select id="Interests">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<aside id="tooltip" class="tooltip">
    Hey, I'm a Tooltip.
    <span id="tooltip_info"></span>
</aside>
```

Note

This needs of course some further improvements. Just an example of how this is possible. And you need to include the jQuery-library in your document, like:

```
<script src="src/js/com.jquery/1.7/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry one question. Your javascript is on another new page?

Comment: You can place the whole `script`-part whithin the `head`-tag. of your page. It can of course – from a validation-poitt-of-view – appear at any place in your document or an external JavaScript-file.

Comment: abit confusing. So i can don't put in my tooltip.html() and put it in my head correct?

Comment: So, when you want to do something with an element, you can place this code in your `head` but you have to use `$(document).ready()` because the browser knows about the elements and their ids first when he's seen them. So this function is executed when the whole dom-structure is loaded and all elements and their ids and classes are known.

Comment: still invalid. I'm replacing the tooltip.html with my sample.php page. Is it this reason that it can't works?

Comment: All the code I have posted lives within the html, that your PHP-file is creating. So it's like you add this to your existing file into the specific parts (like where to put JavaScript, where to put CSS and so on).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13731/discussion-between-jlearner-and-insertusernamehere)

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting to do will not be something implemented in PHP but rather Javascript. PHP involves code that is ran on the `server-side` and does not deal with DOM elements or `client-side` components such as the hover text/tool-tip you are wishing to load. Javascript is parsed by the browsers after the `server-side` code is crunched out and will handle additional changes to your pages after the immediate load.

I recommend you look into learning (or using, if familiar) `jQuery` as it will aid you with your task. It is a Javascript library with simplified bindings for ease of use. There is great documentation and many plugins that use it everyday.

**Reference**: http://jquery.com/

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: no php available ? :( or is there any way to fixed the size of the list-menu ? and <br> to the long sentence?

Comment: It depends on how you would like to trigger resizing the list-menu or adding the break tag. If you would like to execute these actions after page load, it cannot be accomplished with PHP by itself.

Comment: You would still build the tooltips inside php (server-side) where the data comes from, its just we recommend jQuery for the interaction between the user and the page (client-side), so the tooltip changes immediately.

Comment: Any simple samples i can go along ? Never touch jquery before >.<

Answer (score 1):

You want to have content appear on value change within a select box? Use jQuery change() http://jsfiddle.net/PxGEc/1/