# Tooltip using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have tried to call out my document.getElementByID to get the ID from my current form. But it doesn't hover out the specific text that i input rather than it output 'â€‹'. As reference from [Tooltip/hover-text in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416584/tooltip-hover-text-in-an-array), i have amended some stuff but still the tooltip text does not show.

```
Updated code-
In my html page:

<script>
$(document).ready(function () 
{
            var tooltip_Text = $('#tooltip_Text');
    var tooltip = $('#tooltip');
    $('#Hobby').hover(
        function() 
                    {
            tooltip.fadeIn(200);
        },
        function() 
                    {
            setTimeout ( function () {
                tooltip.fadeOut(200); student.php();
            }, 1000);
        }
    );
    $('#Hobby').bind('change', function() 
            {
        student.php('user has changed the value');
    });​
});​
</script>

//my list/menu
<select name="OffenceName" id="Hobby" ><span id="Hobby"></span>
<?php $arr = array('', 'cycling', 'badminton', 'jetskiing', 'ice-skating');
  for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
  {
     echo "<option value=\"{$arr[$i]}\" {$selected}>{$arr[$i]}</option>\n"; 
  }
?>
</select>
<tool id="tooltip" class="tooltip">
<?php $toolarr = array('','cycling is...', 'badmintion is...', 'jetskiing is...', 'ice-skating is...');
  for($t = 0; $t < count($toolarr); $t++)
  {
      if($toolarr[t] == $arr[i])
      {
         echo "sample display";
      }
  }
<span id="tooltip_Text"></span>
```

​

I can't manage to call out the tooltip text below even if i try to get element by id instead of student.php(); Kindly advise.

Comment: Replace  document.getElementById("Hobby") by $("#Hobby")

Comment: Either use full javascript or Jquery. Dont mix them up

Comment: @Tuscan i replaced them but it's still the same. So i cant mix them? I must take out my document.getelementbyid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#Hobby").hover(function(){
        $("#tooltip").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function(){
        $("#tooltip").fadeOut();
    });


    $('#Hobby').change(function() {
      $("#tooltip_Text").text("user has changed the value"); // or you can use .html("...") intead of .text("...")

    });

});​
```

Comment: sorry to disturb, it doesn't alert upon clicking.

Comment: @JLearner My english is not so good. I could'nt understand what you mean clearly? But if you want to change event to click event you can write "click" intead of "change".

Comment: Nope not this. Instead of alert. How can i call the tooltip_text out? I cant put tooltip_text.('user has changed the value') isnt it ?

Comment: Ok it shows! I didn't realise it was at the top of my page. Shouldn't it be inside my <span id="Tooltip_text"> <span>?

Comment: @JLearner  Yes, it shouldn't be inside of select control. If you would like to show that top of page, you can move it after <body> tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should not select the elements with the native javascript selectors but rather with the jQuery selectors. As is stands, your code cant work, because the methods you call only exist, if your elements are wrapped by the jquery Object.

So instead of

```
document.getElementById("Hobby").hover(...
```

use

```
$("#Hobby").hover(...
```

Your code should throw a couple errors like these:

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'hover'
```

EDIT:

couple of errors:

`//my list/menu` is not a valid HTML-comment

`student.php()` is not valid either

Comment: try to change but still the same result "â€‹"

Comment: where is your student.php() function? What the heck is this?

Comment: student.php is my page. Rather than student.html. My page is student.php

Comment: You can't do a call like that in javascript. student.php() calls a function php() on an student object. Both are not existent.

Comment: @JLearner you are totally doing it wrong... and the answer is noway near to that

Comment: @JLearner what do you want to display anyways? Please check your developer console (F12 in Firefox/Chrome/IE and ctrl+shift+i in opera) and fix these errors first.

Comment: Ok. So how can i call it out in the page below ? If I do not link it with my php page? Sorry, i'm never touch before jQuery >.<

Comment: just want to display additional text below once the user click the list.

Comment: `â€‹` is an encoding error - Put some text in your tooltip `<span id="tooltip_Text">Text</span>` and see if this works.

Comment: nope. Still the encoding error. I tried your crtl_sjoft_I, no errors after taking away the student.php